# How to set min max limit and create buckets in python?

Tags: python, pandas, split, segment

I am using spyder IDE for this purpose. The aim is to create buckets with fixed average 30-50 $ across industry segments and only 2 top customers per bucket, it should create a new bucket under same industry segment with extended series 1,2. The split should be automated in such a way- (Example [Aluminium-1,Aluminium-2] and so on.if the average sales is 50$ for 5 customers then the next customer should fall in new bucket with same industry segment name with change in extension series.i.e Aluminium-1,Aluminium-2 and so on.)

```
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir("E:/TNVB1/regression/files")

import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import pandas

data= pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('abc_segment.csv')
print(data)
str(data)
data['Industry_Segment'].value_counts()
n = data.groupby(['Industry_Segment'])['Sales','Top_Cust_count'].agg('sum')
dn =pandas.DataFrame(n)
print(dn)
```

I have grouped by Industry segment with Sales and no of customers. The output is

```
                                                Sales      Top_cust_count
Industry_Segment Customer_Name                                                        
ALUMINIUM        Customer1                       56                0
                 Customer2                       8                0
                 Customer3                       21                0
                 Customer4                      280                1
                 Customer5                       20                0
                 Customer6                       297                1
                 Customer7                        14                0
```

Now the required out put is

```
                            Sales Top_Cust_count
Aluminium-1  Customer1      12       1
Aluminium-1  Customer2       6       0
Aluminium-1  Customer3      13       0
Aluminium-1  Customer4      8        1
Aluminium-1  Customer5      11       0

Aluminum-2   Customer6      16       1
Aluminium-2  Customer7      34       1
```

above is the example of desired split

it has to split automatically to the fixed conditions and go on till no further split is possible.The conditions are each bucket should have max_top_cust_count of 2. and Average $ sales value should be 30-50.

Comment: What are these numbers in the output?

Comment: Thats, Sales in lacs(INR) and count of top customers(Flagged as 0 and 1)

Comment: You do know that rest of the world doesn't use anything called "lacs"?

Comment: Weird isnt't . You may consider this as $.